# PyCharm .spec file error: "RpmSpecTokenType.( or RpmSpecTokenType.: expected, got '='"

Tags: python, pycharm

I've written my first app with Python Tkinter and want to deploy with an executable file. I created a .spec file with pyinstaller and have the following error in the first line of code:

[image: R]

Error message: "RpmSpecTokenType.( or RpmSpecTokenType.: expected, got '='"

I googled the error message and do not find results which is usually indicative of an error I made. However I did follow the directions for pyinstaller correctly and have seen multiple examples here and other places of operational .spec files and mine is identical. I do not know how to solve/debug this error.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Did you run it with python directly?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA I tried to run the app directly from the .exe file, black screen/box flashed briefly and disappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a wrong plugin installed. In PyCharm (or other IntelliJ IDEs) you have [plugin installed](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12552-rpm-spec-file) for `.spec` files that inspect RMP Spec files, not `.spec` files for `pyinstaller`. As far as I know there is no plugin for `.spec` files for pyinstaller, and actually there is no need to have a plugin as `.spec` file for pyinstaller is just a plain Python script and you can configure your IDE to open it as a regular Python file.

Comment: Thank you @Maksim for responding. I haven't touched Python since this course but it's good to have what is likely the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Settings->Plugins->RPM SPEC File->Uninstall Plugin

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just unistalled the RPM spec file from IDE's plugin page, works fine now.